# Where are official changes announced by Wizard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

At events and on conversation boards everyone is has stated that as Khans comes out M14 and the Return to Ravnica block is going to be rotating out of standard. I can't find any reason this would happen other than that "that is what happened in the past". As Magic has a very structured system I would imagine there is an official feed/site somewhere from Wizards that announces and clarifies such things.

Comment: "that is what happened in the past" because the Standard season is on a schedule, much like a season of your favorite TV show. The schedule is changing in fall 2015 (both current answers have linked to that announcement), but until then the schedule remains intact, and that means the oldest core set and block in Standard rotates out at the same time as the first set from the new block rotates in.

Comment: @Rainbolt I don't think that's the first question along those lines - if we want to consolidate, we should probably look at: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-can-i-tell-which-sets-are-currently-legal-in-various-formats http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12248/what-are-the-most-popular-formats-for-magic-the-gathering http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/what-are-the-legal-tournament-formats-for-mtg and maybe others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoTC has a tradition of reorganize/changing their webpage, so I cannot guarantee this link will work consistently in the future, but they generally post it on their webpage someplace (I found this using Google + "mtg standard format")

http://magic.wizards.com/en/content/standard-formats-magic-gathering

> Standard format uses the two most recently-released blocks, as well as
>   the current core set. When a new block is launched, the oldest block
>   rotates out of the list. The following card sets are currently
>   permitted in standard format:
>
> ```
> Khans of Tarkir (effective September 26, 2014)
> Magic 2015
> Journey into Nyx
> Born of the Gods
> Theros
> Magic 2014 (until September 26, 2014)
> Dragon's Maze (until September 26, 2014)
> Gatecrash (until September 26, 2014)
> Return to Ravnica (until September 26, 2014)
> ```

note: The quote in this answer is going to become outdated soon.  [Wizards has announced a change](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/mm/metamorphosis) in how cards are released and how it will impact the standard format.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is changing after this standard season, with the removal of the core set & change from three set blocks to two. See http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/mm/metamorphosis for the long explanation.

Comment: I find it sad that only now am I discovering the subdomain [magic.wizards.com](http://magic.wizards.com). Google has always directed me to [archive.wizards.com](http://archive.wizards.com) when I search, which would explain why I couldn't find the current information on the site.

Comment: @Fr33dan I'm pretty sure that when they redesigned the website a couple months ago, they moved all the old content to archive.wizards.com, so an awful lot of the things you find will be there, especially if there hasn't been any need to post a new version of something. (But as Colin points out here, searching for \[mtg standard format\] does lead you to the current site.)

Comment: @Jefromi Maybe for you it does, but I clicked on the archive site so Google's algorithm now knows I "prefer" that site. Just like if I google "trample" even though it has many meanings my first result is the MTG Salvation page on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The list of sets legal in any format can be found in [The MTG Tournament Rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_en.pdf), Section 6. The sets legal for Standard, in particular, can be found at [this rules page](http://magic.wizards.com/en/content/standard-formats-magic-gathering). Historically, a block rotates out when the block after the following one is introduced, and a core set rotates out when the block after the following core set is introduced. However, [Wizards is changing this](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/mm/metamorphosis), and in the future, core sets will be removed, blocks will be two sets each, and the most recent three blocks will be legal.

Comment: My question is, if it is a "well-defined rotation of sets", where is the rotation defined? "Historically" is not a definition. Are you saying we just follow articles like the one linked for the definition?

Comment: I added sources. The "Historically" sentence is now sourced from the link in the previous sentence.